# C# EFCore.BulkExtensions The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, foreign-keys, efcore.bulkextensions

Parent:

```
public class Currency
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

Child:

```
public class CurrencyRate
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,6)")]
    public decimal Value { get; set; }

    public virtual Currency? Currency { get; set; }
}
```

Seed:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Currency>().HasData(
    new Currency { Id = 1, Name = "JPY" },
    new Currency { Id = 2, Name = "USD" },
    new Currency { Id = 3, Name = "EUR" },
    new Currency { Id = 4, Name = "TRY" }
);
```

Insert:

```
public async Task UpdateCurrencyRates()
{
    var trackedCurrencies = await _context.Currency.ToListAsync();

    BulkConfig bulkConfig = new BulkConfig()
    {
        IncludeGraph = true,
        SetOutputIdentity = true,
        CalculateStats = true,
        PropertiesToIncludeOnUpdate = new List<string> { string.Empty }
    };
   
    List<CurrencyRate> currencyRates = GetCurrencyRatesFromSomewhere();

    currencyRates.ForEach(currencyRate =>
    {
        var trackedCurrency = trackedCurrencies.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Name == currencyRate.Currency?.Name);
        if (trackedCurrency != null)
        {
            currencyRate.Currency = trackedCurrency;
        }
        else if (currencyRate.Currency != null)
        {
            trackedCurrencies.Add(currencyRate.Currency);
        }
    });


    _context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(currencyRates, bulkConfig);
}
```

The above code works well unless new currency comes in (the one not included in Seed). Then I get 'The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint'. Why is it so? From what I read BulkExtensions should insert new currency first, then update CurrencyRates with its Id and only then perform insert of CurrencyRates.

Update:
If I do this, it works, but that defeats the grace of the BulkInsert:

```
currencyRates.ForEach(async currencyRate =>
{
    var trackedCurrency = trackedCurrencies.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Name == currencyRate.Currency?.Name);
    if (trackedCurrency != null)
    {
        currencyRate.Currency = trackedCurrency;            
    }
    else if (currencyRate.Currency != null)
    {
        trackedCurrencies.Add(currencyRate.Currency);
        //this line added
        await _context.AddAsync(currencyRate.Currency);

    }
});

//this line added
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: What does "new currency comes in" mean? [mre] [ask]

Comment: ``conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint`` it about you are inserting an CurrencyId into CurrencyRate that not exist in the Currency table and that make sense.

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad BulkExtensions should handle it - it inserts new currency first, then returns it's Id. But for some reason it fails

Comment: It's better to see translated tsql by ef bulk extensions!

Comment: Have you tried to add the new currencies first (add them to the database with a commit) and then update the currency rates in a 2nd step? I am asking this because to me it seems that the conflict comes directly back from the SQL server (which is why EF fails to detect it beforehand).

Comment: @Matt yes, that's how I ended up doing it. But it takes 2 commits and more lines of code.  Does BulkExtensions not supposed to handle this? What is the point of IncludeGraph then?

Comment: @NickFarsi - Seems to be not the case. If you need it as atomic operation, consider putting it into a transaction.

Comment: You're correct, EF bulk extensions should include the child entities hence the `IncludeGraph` option. However, why are you doing `trackedCurrencies.Add`? Get rid of your entire `foreach` loop and just do `BulkInsertOrUpdate` - EF bulk extensions is clever enough to do whatever you're trying to achieve there. Does that fix the issue?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary the reason is that GetCurrencyRatesFromSomewhere() does not return tracked currencies (their Ids are 0) So as I understand I should first assign tracked currencies to currency rates. Otherwise I end up with several CurrencyRates entries with untracked currencies with same currency name and EF tries to insert all of them and fails because of unique name constraint